# In what context would one use "Ich drück' dich"?

Tags: meaning, translation, meaning-in-context

Is it a common way to say goodbye? 
I understand it is informal, but what would be an appropriate situation/context for using it?

Comment: A bit like norwegian klem, to hug. Although both words in a more general sense mean to squeeze.

Comment: Familiärer, entsexualisierter Kontext.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*drücken* is used in the meaning of "to hug" here. So it basically means "I'm hugging you". That wouldn't necessarily be said to someone who is present with you (you can hug them without saying so), but rather in writing or on the phone. Don't use it with anyone you wouldn't hug physically.

Comment: Maybe worthwhile to add: The social context is among close friends, loved ones, family. It's like signing an email with "hugs", perhaps slightly more intimate.

Comment: @henning: In the context of online text chat, it sounds to me like the final words of a _very_ intimate exchange... ;)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase sounds a bit unusual to me. One would rather say "Fühl dich (von mir) gedrückt.", which is normally used to console someone but can also be used in addition to saying goodbye.

Comment: I've never heard "Fühl dich gedrückt", but I've often heard "Ich drück' dich". Maybe there's a regional difference

Comment: Seems so, I'm in xehpuk's camp, @PiedPiper. ;)